# Post method not return value

Tags: php

I just want to share my details to another php file using POST with Ajax, in my code the post value not initiated to share,

Here is my code :

```
<?php
include('database_connection.php');

if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
    // some logic





    // some logic

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
    $output = '';
    if($total_row > 0)
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-4 col-md-3">
                <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; padding:10px; margin-bottom:16px; height:300px;">
                    <audio controls controlsList="nodownload" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;margin-left: -21px;">
                        <source src="audio_sample/'. $row['voice_audio_file'] .'" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    </audio>
                    <p align="center"><strong> '. $row['voice_name'] .'</strong></p>

                    <p style="font-size: 12px;">

                    Voice Id          : '. $row['voice_id'].' <br />
                    Voice Name        : '. $row['voice_name'].' <br />
                    Gender            : '. $row['voice_gender'].' <br />
                    Genres            : '. $row['voice_genres'].' <br />
                    Voice Modulation  : '. $row['voice_voice_modulation'].' <br />
                    Languages         : '. $row['voice_languages'].' <br />
                    Jingle Moods      : '. $row['voice_jingle_moods'].' <br />
                    Ivr               : '. $row['voice_ivr'].' <br /> </p>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 5px 83px 5px 83px;
                    "data-voice-id="'.$row["voice_id"].'
                    " data-voice-name="'.$row["voice_name"].'
                    "data-voice-id="'.$row["voice_gender"].'">Add to Playlist</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            ';
        } 
    }
    else 
    {
        $output = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
    }
    echo $output;
}
?>
<script>
    $('.btn').on('click',function() {

        var voice_id = $(this).data("voice_id");
        var voice_name = $(this).data("voice_name");
        var voice_gender = $(this).data("voice_gender");

        $.ajax({
            method   : "POST",
            url      : "manage_cart.php",
            datatype : "text",
            data     : 
            { 
                voice_id: voice_id, voice_name: voice_name, voice_gender: voice_gender 
            },
            success: function(data)
            {   
                // console.log(data);
            console.log('success',data);


            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

I want to share voice_id, voice_name, voice_gender to manage_cart.php,
my manage_cart.php file,

```
 <?php 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

$voice_id = '';   
$voice_name = ''; 
$voice_gender = ''; 

if(isset($_POST['voice_id']) && isset($_POST['voice_name']) && isset($_POST['voice_gender']) )
{
    $voice_id   = $_POST['voice_id'];
    $voice_name = $_POST['voice_name'];
    $voice_name = $_POST['voice_gender'];
}
    echo $voice_id ."&". $voice_name ."&". $voice_gender;

 ?>
```

Here my post value not pass to manage_cart.php.

How can i solve the issue?

Comment: You need to set datatype to json `dataType: "json"`

Comment: still not working after update json

Comment: my output : https://snag.gy/xWU8Kg.jpg

Comment: Check at the bottom of the “Headers” tab, what parameters your request actually contains.

Comment: And add some logging to console in the JS part, to verify your variables actually contain what you think they do.

Answer (score 0):

Your button attribute doesn't have `data-voice-gender`. There are duplicate `data-voice-id`, and use the same style of variable like `data-voice-id` but in javascript you're using `$(this).data('voice_id')`

Comment: Try to use `$(this).data('voice-id')`, same as for `voice-gender` and `voice-name`